# How to disable editing of elements in combobox for c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have some elements in a ComboBox (WinForms with C#). I want their content to be static so that a user cannot change the values inside when the application is ran. I also do not want the user adding new values to the ComboBox

Answer (score 339, accepted):

Use the ComboStyle property:

```
comboBox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
```

Comment: This can also be set in the properties window of the designer.

Comment: With recent versions you can use `combo.Properties.TextEditStyle = DisableTextEditor`

Answer (score 23):

This is another method I use because changing `DropDownSyle` to `DropDownList` makes it look 3D and sometimes its just plain ugly.

You can prevent user input by handling the `KeyPress` event of the ComboBox like this.

```
private void ComboBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
      e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: You can change its appearence in the designer, FlatStyle :)

Comment: @StinkyCat That doesn't change the look of the popped up list, only the control in the form.

Comment: You have to handle right click menu where you have option `Paste` too. I've no idea how right now.

Comment: Ok, to remove `Paste` you will have to create fake empty context menu and assign it to the ComboBox.

Answer (score 13):

Yow can change the DropDownStyle in properties to DropDownList. This will not show the TextBox for filter.

[image: DropDownStyle Property]
<sub>(Screenshot provided by [FUSION CHA0S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9754937/fusion-cha0s).)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I tried ComboBox1_KeyPress but it allows to delete the character & you can also use copy paste command. My DropDownStyle is set to DropDownList but still no use. So I did below step to avoid combobox text editing.

- Below code handles delete & backspace key. And also disables combination with control key (e.g. ctr+C or ctr+X)

  ```
   Private Sub CmbxInType_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles CmbxInType.KeyDown
      If e.KeyCode = Keys.Delete Or e.KeyCode = Keys.Back Then 
          e.SuppressKeyPress = True
      End If

      If Not (e.Control AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.C) Then
          e.SuppressKeyPress = True
      End If
  End Sub
  ```
- In form load use below line to disable right click on combobox
  control to avoid cut/paste via mouse click.

  ```
  CmbxInType.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu()
  ```