# How to prevent manual input into a ComboBox in C#

Tags: c#, string, combobox

I have a form in C# that uses a `ComboBox`.
How do I prevent a user from manually inputting text in the `ComboBox` in C#?

```
this.comboBoxType.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 15.75F);
this.comboBoxType.FormattingEnabled = true;
this.comboBoxType.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
            "a",
            "b",
            "c"});
this.comboBoxType.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(742, 364);
this.comboBoxType.Name = "comboBoxType";
this.comboBoxType.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(89, 32);
this.comboBoxType.TabIndex = 57;
```

I want A B C to be the only options.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable editing of elements in combobox for c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598447/how-to-disable-editing-of-elements-in-combobox-for-c)

Answer (score 177, accepted):

Just set your combo as a DropDownList:

```
this.comboBoxType.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
```

Comment: Doing this, does not allow me to put in default 'Select A Item' text?

Comment: Just add `this.comboBoxType.SelectedIndex = 0;` to set the "default" to be the first item at the end of your code block above.

Answer (score 24):

I believe you want to set the DropDownStyle to DropDownList.

```
this.comboBoxType.DropDownStyle = 
    System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
```

Alternatively, you can do this from the WinForms designer by selecting the control, going to the Properties Window, and changing the "DropDownStyle" property to "DropDownList".

Answer (score 8):

You can suppress handling of the key press by adding `e.Handled = true` to the control's KeyPress event:

```
private void Combo1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: You can still right-click selected text in the combo box and hit Cut, voila, text disappeared

Comment: Even you can able to delete the character.

Answer (score 2):

I like to keep the ability to manually insert stuff, but limit the selected items to what's in the list. 
I'd add this event to the ComboBox. As long as you get the SelectedItem and not the Text, you get the correct predefined items; a, b and c.

```
private void cbx_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!(sender is ComboBox cbx)) return;
  int i;
  cbx.SelectedIndex = (i = cbx.FindString(cbx.Text)) >= 0 ? i : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why use ComboBox then?

C# has a control called [Listbox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Technically a ComboBox's difference on a Listbox is that a ComboBox can receive input, so if it's not the control you need then i suggest you use `ListBox`

Listbox Consumption guide here: [C# ListBox](http://www.dotnetperls.com/listbox)