# Prevent ComboBox color change when DropDownStyle set to DropDownList

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a ComboBox in Winforms for which I want to prevent text to be written into it, so the selected option is guaranteed to be one of the options from the list

To do so, I set `DropDownStyle` to `DropDownList` as explained in this question

[How to prevent manual input into a ComboBox in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9648381/how-to-prevent-manual-input-into-a-combobox-in-c-sharp)

However doing so, the color of the dropdown changes to gray.
For asthetic reasons I would like the dropown to continue being white.

The BackColor is set to `Window` but I have tried changing it to `White` and it still keeps being gray.

Is there a way of forcing it to be White even if the input type is DropDownList?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is not, strictly speaking, gray.  The user must select from the list and cannoy type something into the text portion in that style, so it is disabled and therefore displays the disabled color selected by the user.  It is much less about decor and more about visual cues.

Comment: Yes, I know why it turns into the disabled color, but I want to force it not to do so. I don't want to change the disabled color since I want "trully" disabled input fields to be gray. To me a dropdown list should have the color disabled only if changing its value is disabled, which is not the case.