# Combo box c# not allow modify selected index

Tags: c#, combobox, edit, selectedindex

I got a **combobox** and i want that the string of the **selected index** will not be possible to edit
how can i do it?
thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do ? String of SelectedIndex ?

Comment: I have a combobox and when the user choose between  options he can modify the text. i want that he will couldn't do that

Comment: It's not String of SelectedIndex.

Comment: I mean what is now selected

Comment: Take a look first before asking the same questions that others have previously asked, such as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/598447/how-to-disable-editing-of-elements-in-combobox-for-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to block the ability to edit the textbox portion of a combobox you should set

```
 combobox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
```

or set the same property using the Properties list in the Form Designer

Answer (score 0):

```
  private void combobox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
  {
      e.Handled = true;
  }
```