# .Net Combo Box simple style without edit

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How to disable editing or hide text edit field, when `DropDownStyle = Simple` for Combo Box control?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13263335/1300049

Comment: Is it `ComboBoxStyle.Simple` or `ComboBoxStyle.DropDownSimple`?

Answer (score 0):

MSDN on [ComboBox.DropDownStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.dropdownstyle.aspx):

> The DropDownStyle property specifies whether the list is always displayed or whether the list is displayed in a drop-down. **The DropDownStyle property also specifies whether the text portion can be edited.**

Docs on [ComboBoxStyle.Simple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.comboboxstyle.aspx):

> Specifies that the list is always visible and that the text portion is editable. This means that the user can enter a new value and is not limited to selecting an existing value in the list.

So, `ComboBoxStyle.Simple` suggests that list can be edited by user and it's confusing to disable edit with this `DropDownStyle` selected. Alternatives:

- If you are ok with drop-down list use `ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList`
- If you want to display a non-editable list with a view similar to `ComboBoxStyle.Simple` consider using [ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.aspx)

Comment: ListView leaves focus, when user trying other controls

Comment: @mcuw Doesn't ComboBox do the same? By the way, why do you need to hold focus on control? And I said `ListBox` not `ListView`.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to achieve this effect on Combox you can just catch the events like "TextChanged" and then setting it back to "" and asking  if (!comboBox1.DropDownStyle == ComboBoxStyle.Simple) before adding items to Items collection. Although it seems there are better ways to achive similar functionality using listbox as suggested before.