# Prevent text editing in combobox without using DrpoDownList style

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox

Okay. I want to block text editing in combobox but i don't like 'DropDownList' style. Because it looking like a disabled control (changes color unlike other controls). i have 2 options now, i will prevent text editing with using 'DropDown' style or i will change the appearance of ComboBox with using 'DropDownList' style. Any idea?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13263335/14171304

Comment: @dr.null, when I do this, all key functions are also blocked. Functions such as searching by letter or scrolling with the arrow keys are disabled. In this case i prefer to use 'DropDownList' style.